# How to make POST request in my app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resources, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use $resource to make post request.

In my app,

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Product', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource( '/api/product/:id', {
                id: '@id'
            }, {
                   'save': {
                    method: 'POST',
                    isArray: true,
                    url: '/api/product/:id/addProduct' 
                    //different url for adding a product.
                ,}
            }
        );
    }
]);
```

In my controller

```
Product.save({
                name:'test name',
                quantity:'5'
            })
```

It made the request through url like

```
/api/product/addProduct    //without id
```

but if I do

```
Product.save({
                id:'12345',
                name:'test name',
                quantity:'5'
            })
```

The request url is correct like `/api/product/12345/addProduct`
but the payload become

```
id:'12345',
name:'test name',
quantity:'5'
```

The server won't take id parameter as payload.
I am not sure how to make the post request. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass 'id' object as first argument in save method:

```
Product.save({"id":"12345"}, {
                    name:'test name',
                    quantity:'5'
                })
```

Working code: http://jsfiddle.net/7rx5fqx2/1/